# How can I log out from my account on askubuntu?

Tags: support

How can I log out from my account on this forum? Maybe I am just missing something obvious, but so far I haven't found out how to log out. I have tried everything I can think of …

I also couldn't find any hint among existing questions on the forum, nor in the help center. That's why I assume it must be very obvious, and for some reason I just don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the grey Stack Exchange logo in the top right beside the grey question mark.

[image: Stack Logo]

Then, besides Ask Ubuntu, click "Log out".

[image: Ask Ubuntu]

Remember, questions like this should be added to [Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com).

Comment: Oh my goodness, why didn't I see it? Thanks a lot! _/\_